# Renew access token with refresh token from personal api

Tags: javascript, angular, jwt

I have a personal REST API which i am calling from an angular 2 client. My current authentication process is as follows:

1. User login with email/password
2. Server validates and sends user_data, access_token(JWT) and refresh_token(opaque token which is stored in the database) back to client.
3. Client sends access_token on every request.

On my API, i have and endpoint `getAccessToken(String email, String refresh_token)` which validates refresh_token and issues a new access_token.

My question is: what method should i use to request for a new access_token before or after it expires using my refresh_token from my angular2 app.

I'm currently thinking of checking for access_token expiration before each http request to the API as follows:

```
if (!tokenNotExpired("accessToken")) {
    this.classService.getAccessToken().subscribe(
        data => {
            // store new access_token in localStorage, then make request to get resource.
            this.classService.createClass().subscribe(
                data => {
                    //success
                }, error => {
                    //error
                })
        }, error => {
            // Invalid refresh token, redirect to login page.
        });
} else {
    this.classService.createClass().subscribe(
        data => {
            //success
        }, error => {
            //error
        });
}
```

Is there a better method to do this? I'm using angular2-jwt for token verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems quite alright. But if you have many different API calls (e.g. not only `createClass()` but also `updateClass()` and `destroyClass()`) you might end up with having to do the same token expiration check in many different places of your source code and that's never a good thing.

What about creating one service which will take care of token expiration/renewal for all your calls?

This service will work as a factory for observables. You tell it which endpoint should be contacted and what data to send to the endpoint. The service will return an observable based on your API request. And if the token is expired, it will wrap your observable in a token refresh call.

This is just a pseudo code to get the general idea:

```
class ApiService
{
    constructor (private http: Http){}

    createRequest (endpoint, payload):Observable<any>
    {
        let request = 
        this.http.post(endpoint, payload, {headers:auth}).map(/* ... */);

        if (tokenExpired())
        {
          return this.refreshToken().flatMap( 
            (token) => {return request});
        }
        else
          return request;
    }

    refreshToken():Observable<string>
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

With this service you don't have to check for token expiration anywhere else. Just make sure you use the service to construct your API calls, i.e. inside your `createClass()` method.

You can even enhance `createRequest` method by a parameter which will allow to switch off the authorization (e.g. for endpoints which don't require authorization). Another parameter could be used to create calls with different HTTP methods (PUT, GET).

Comment: Thanks. You helped a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to mimic good old sliding expiration:

In auth.guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable }                 from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate }        from '@angular/router';
import { tokenNotExpired,
         JwtHelper }                  from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  private jwtHelper = new JwtHelper();

  constructor(private router: Router) {}


  tokenValid() {
    this.handleSlidingExpiration();
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

  canActivate() {
    if (tokenNotExpired()) {
      this.handleSlidingExpiration();
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }

  private handleSlidingExpiration() {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    if (!token) { return; }

    let expirationDate = this.jwtHelper.getTokenExpirationDate(token);
    let dToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
    let refreshLimit = new Date((dToken.iat + (dToken.exp - dToken.iat) / 2) * 1000);

    if(new Date() > refreshLimit) {
      // Here you can make a new side request for the new token and update it in local storage
    }
  }
}
```